# Adsense not displaying on HTC Hero

Tags: android, adsense, htc-hero

We've been developing an Android application which includes Google Adsense. However there seems to be a problem with the ads not showing on HTC Hero phones. It does show on HTC Magic. Have anyone else had the same problem? Are there any Hero-specific settings which is needed?

Comment: No upvote for you, but +1 for the HTC Hero. :-)

Comment: If you can host it i'll download it and test it out on my Hero (UK).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, It used to be a common problem in the early stage of AdSense SDK for Android. But now they have fixed it. Actually it was fixed in early january 2010. Shame on me for not seeing your question before now...

;-)